# Apply changes on all the hidden rows in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have table with number of records where one of the columns is having a dropdown list. Based on the value in one of the columns the options/values in the select needs to be removed. I am able to do this, but the changes are applied to the first set of records that are shown on the screen. The rest of the records in the other pages of the table is not affected. I initially used the following syntax to access the table data

```
$('table tr').each(function(){...});
```

Since the above code is not fetching the hidden rows, I used the `fnGetNodes()` to access the all the rows. Following is the complete code to access and modify the contents.

```
var rows=oTable.fnGetNodes();
for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
    var index=5;
    var grade=$(rows[i]).find('td').eq(index).text();
    var desc=$(rows[i]).find('td').eq(index+1).text();  
    console.log('Grade - '+grade);
    console.log('Desc - '+desc);
    index=13;
    var selID=$(rows[i]).find('td').eq(index).find('select').attr('id');
    if(grade.match('Used')){            
        $("select#"+selID).attr('disabled', true);
        $("select#"+selID).css("background-color","#eeeeee");
    }
    else if(desc.match('ALT$') || desc.match('MTM$'))
    {   
        $("#"+selID+" option[value='Option one']").remove();
    }
}
```

I am able to print the id of the select element, but not able to change it. Its again working for the first set of records shown on the screen and not for the hidden ones. Can you please let me know what I am missing?

Comment: Approach is all wrong. There is a lot more under the hood of the plugin than just the html. It caches data and html internally. Update the data that renders the select through the data api...then do a redraw

Comment: @charlietfl, I am new to jQuery. Can you please tell me how to use data api? I am using Struts, which loads data into datatable.

Comment: loads it how? as html rendered in page or json passed to plugin?

Comment: @charlietfl, Its not json, Values in the java object are loaded into JSP, which is finally a html file, on which the jquery datatable properties is applied.

Comment: browser has no knowledge of the jsp...just the html. reason I asked is there are several ways to build the table.

Comment: @charlietfl, Do you have any suggestion or example that would help me fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code as follows:

```js
// ... skipped ...

var $select = $(rows[i]).find('td').eq(index).find('select');
if(grade.match('Used')){            
    $select
       .attr('disabled', true)
       .css("background-color","#eeeeee");
}
else if(desc.match('ALT$') || desc.match('MTM$'))
{   
    $select.find("option[value='Option one']").remove();
}

// ... skipped ...
```

Comment: @davidkonrad, thanks for the demo, added to the answer.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, its not about accessing the hidden rows, but modifying their behaviors. Again, after modifying the code per your suggestion, I see that the changes are not reflected to the hidden rows. However, its working fine for the first set of rows on the first page.

Comment: @Anand, sorry I misread your question and will correct my answer.